Krishna taking 16100 women for his 'own pleasure'
The linga purana 1.69.82 states :
The excessively strong one, of unequalled exploit, Kṛṣṇa took up sixteen thousand one hundred girls for his own pleasure.
This is completely different from the version in srimad bhagavatam and tarnishes the character of krishna how do vaishnavs respond

How does it tarnish the image of Bhagwan Sri Krishna? These cherry picked statements of English translations of Hindu texts float around the internet and gullible chaps fall prey.
Coming to Linga Purana Chapter 69, it elaborates on the lineage and activities of Krishna.  The verses 81-82 tell how Krishna killed Narakasura and took 16108 girls for his 'Upabhoga'. Now, 'Upabhoga' is not pleasure. In all Hindi translations of Linga Purana, the word Upabhoga has been used as it is. 'Upabhoga' simply means in this context (and also used otherwise as this meaning) as 'cohabitation' or 'marital pleasure'. In short, here it just means Krishna married 16108 girls after killing Narakasura.
Except for the crappy English translations, there is nothing derogatory here.
The original Sanskrit Verse goes like this


Could u send me the original sanskrit verse it'll be helpful

@Titaniumww7 updated in the answer.

Send verse 82 as well

@Titaniumww7 updated.
